# Automating Zoom.us app with applescript

Tags: applescript, zoom.app

I'm helping disabled person to adapt Zoom application for their special needs.
The problem is that zoom exposes only `raise hand` reaction via `Option + y` keyboard shortcut.

My goal is to let this person express other reactions like `yes`, `no` and `...` using keyboard shortcuts connected to special equipment.

I find it challenging to access the `reactions` menu via Applescript.
[image: reaction menu]

Additionally, zoom shows menu with `reactions` button only when user hover mouse.

[image: bottom menu that requires hover to reveal]

I started my script as

```
tell application "zoom.us"
    activate
end tell
try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "zoom.us"
            tell window "Zoom Meeting"

-- some magic that reveals menu with buttons and press reactions button goes here

            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
on error errMsg
    display dialog "Error: " & errMsg
end try
```

Thanks for your help!